# R:How can I get argument literally?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a function `f`:

```
f <- function() 1
```

I want to know if it's possible to define a function `g` so that `g(f(1))` outputs `"f(1)"`, which means it returns the argument literally as string before looking up definition of `f` in the environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
foo <- function(x) deparse(substitute(x))
f <- function() {1}
> foo(f(1))
[1] "f(1)"
```

Comment: handy for auto-generating graph labels, btw!